# Fazer div aparecer para apenas alguns usuários do site

Tags: php, html

Queria fazer um div que só apareça para alguma parcela de pessoas que acessarem o meu site, como faço isso?

Comment: Qual o critério da segregação?

Comment: Você precisa de garantias que as pessoas não acessem isto ou só um facilitador para ocultar o que não deve ser visto?

Comment: preciso que seja como se fosse um sorteio de quem verá o anúncio.

Answer (score 3):

Se for por exemplo baseado em um usuário estar logado poderia ser feito desta forma:

Eu divido minha pagina em pequenos arquivos php (com elementos HTML puro) e verifico se o usuário esta logado se sim a página será composta com um botão logout caso não com botões login e cadastro.

```
session_start();
    if((!isset($_SESSION['email']) == true) and (!isset($_SESSION['pass']) == true)){
            require_once 'components/modals/login-modal.php';
            require_once 'components/modals/create-account-modal.php';
        }else{
            require_once 'components/modals/logout-modal.php';
        }
```

Desta forma será segredado as divs

Também é possível segregar baseados em outros quesitos como o navegador do usuário:

```
  <?php
    $useragent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

  if (preg_match('|MSIE ([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})|',$useragent,$matched)) {
    $browser_version=$matched[1];
    $browser = 'IE';
  } elseif (preg_match( '|Opera/([0-9].[0-9]{1,2})|',$useragent,$matched)) {
    $browser_version=$matched[1];
    $browser = 'Opera';
  } elseif(preg_match('|Firefox/([0-9\.]+)|',$useragent,$matched)) {
    $browser_version=$matched[1];
    $browser = 'Firefox';
  } elseif(preg_match('|Chrome/([0-9\.]+)|',$useragent,$matched)) {
    $browser_version=$matched[1];
    $browser = 'Chrome';
  } elseif(preg_match('|Safari/([0-9\.]+)|',$useragent,$matched)) {
    $browser_version=$matched[1];
    $browser = 'Safari';
  } else {
    $browser_version = 0;
    $browser= 'other';
  }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <?php 
              if($browser == 'Safari'){
                  echo '<span id="#internal">Safari</span>';
              }else{
                  echo '<span>Outro navegador</span>';
              }
         ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Baseado na string contida em `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` (Super Global) é possível identificar por comparação de strings qual o Browser, Versão e até SO (em alguns casos).

Comment: É porque estou fazendo um site e quero colocar propaganda, mas o site só vai ter mais ou menos uma página e eu quero colocar a minha forma de propaganda, e caso no futuro o site tiver varios pedidos de anuncios,ficaria muito poluido por propaganda, então eu queria fazer um sistema que faça por exemplo assim "20% das pessoas que acessarem verão essa propaganda,outros vinte verão outra propaganda".

Comment: @Luvinicius, qual seria o critério para alcançar esses 20% (local, idade, sexo...). Mesmo à revelia, esses `20%` teria como base o total de acessos anterior - *creio que seja a estimativa mais simples de aplicar*.

Comment: Mas não tem como por exemplo "sortear" os 20% que verão a propaganda?